# How to pass a C# double[] to a C++ function that requires constant double* pArr? C++, C#

Tags: c#, c++, constants, marshalling

I  have a function in C++ written as:

```
MyFunc(const double* pArray, int length);
```

I need to pass a non-constant array into it:

```
//C#
double[] myDoubleArray = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

MyFunc(myDoubleArray, 5);
```

The program is breaking when I do this.

edit:

```
//C# declaration

[DllImport(@"RTATMATHLIB.dll", EntryPoint = "?MyFunc@@YANPBNHHHH@Z")]
public static extern double MyFunc(double[] data, int length);

//C# usage
public static double MyFunc(double[] data)
{
    return MyFunc(data, data.Length);
}

//C++ export
__declspec(dllexport) double MyFunc(const double* data, int length);


//C++ signature
double MyFunc(const double* data, int length)
{
    return 0; //does not quite matter what it returns...
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your declaration of MyFunc in C#? Also, what means "the program is breaking"? Do you get a compiler error/runtime error/unexpected results?

Comment: Can you post the Import attribute and MyFunc signature?

Comment: Also add `extern "C"` to your export line to export it without name mangling so you can reference it by its actual name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass a non-constant array to a function requiring a constant array. The const qualifier to the array implies that the function will not modify the contents of the array. The array does not need to be constant before passing to the function; the function will not modify the contents, due to the const in the declaration

Answer (score 0):

Constness can be trivially added. Your program is not wrong. You must have missed some other detail.